# Cambiar tamaño imagen con php

Tags: php, gd

Estoy tratando de redimensionar una imagen y crear una miniatura pero debo tener algo mal que no consigo ver que no lo hace.

en principio la imagen sube perfectamente y detecta el tamaño ( o por lo menos eso parece por los avisos ) crea una imagen en el servidor vacia.

esta es mi funcion:

```
    function Subir_Imagen($Input, $Ruta, $Foto, $Miniatura, $AnchoMax, $AltoMax){

    $Respuesta = array();
    $NombreOriginal  = basename($_FILES[$Input]['name']);
    $Extension = pathinfo($NombreOriginal, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if ($Foto != '') { //Si el nombre esta vacio uso el orginal
        $Nombre = $Foto.'.'.$Extension;
    } else {
        $Nombre = $_FILES[$Input]['name'];
    }

//Ruta de los archivos
    $ImagenOriginal = $Ruta.basename($Nombre);
    $ImagenMini = $Ruta."Mini_".basename($Nombre);

//Subo la imagen
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$Input]['tmp_name'],$ImagenOriginal)) {
        //redimensiono la imagen si es demasiado grande.
        if ($Extension == "jpg" || $Extension == "jpeg") { $ImagenGrande = imagecreatefromjpeg($ImagenOriginal);
            } elseif ($Extension == "png") { $ImagenGrande = imagecreatefrompng($ImagenOriginal);
            } elseif ($Extension == "gif") { $ImagenGrande = imagecreatefromgif($ImagenOriginal);
            }

        $x = imagesx($ImagenGrande);
        $y = imagesy($ImagenGrande);

        if($x <= $AnchoMax && $y <= $AltoMax){
            $Respuesta['Script'] .= "Alerta('La imagen ya estaba optimizada.','success',3000);";
            return json_encode($Respuesta);
        }
        if ($x >= $y) {
            $nuevax = $AnchoMax;
            $nuevay = $nuevax * $y / $x;
            $Mininuevay = 400 * $y / $x;
        } else {
            $nuevay = $AltoMax;
            $nuevax = $x / $y * $nuevay;
            $Mininuevax = 400 / $y * $nuevay;
        }

        $ImagenRedimensionada = imagecreatetruecolor($nuevax, $nuevay);
        imagecopyresized($ImagenRedimensionada, $ImagenGrande, 0, 0, 0, 0, floor($Mininuevax), floor($Mininuevay), $x, $y);

        if ($Extension == "jpg" || $Extension == "jpeg") { imagejpeg($ImagenRedimensionada,$ImagenOriginal,100);
            } elseif ($Extension == "png") { imagepng($ImagenRedimensionada,$ImagenOriginal,100);
            } elseif ($Extension == "gif") { imagegif($ImagenRedimensionada,$ImagenOriginal,100); }
            imagedestroy($ImagenRedimensionada);

    if($Miniatura == "SI") { //creo la miniatura
            $Miniatura = imagecreatetruecolor($Mininuevax, $Mininuevay);
            imagecopyresized($Miniatura, $ImagenGrande, 0, 0, 0, 0, floor($nuevax), floor($nuevay), $x, $y);

        if ($Extension == "jpg" || $Extension == "jpeg") { imagejpeg($Miniatura,$ImagenMini,100);
            } elseif ($Extension == "png") { imagepng($Miniatura,$ImagenMini,100);
            } elseif ($Extension == "gif") { imagegif($Miniatura,$ImagenMini,100); }
            imagedestroy($Miniatura);
    }

        $Respuesta['Script'] .= "Alerta('La imagen se ha ".$Miniatura." optimizado ".$ImagenMini." correctamente.','success',3000);";
    return json_encode($Respuesta);
    }
}
```

Para subirla uso esto:

```
$FondoPantalla = 
Subir_Imagen('Empresa_Desktop',$RutImg,'Desktop','SI','800','600');
```

¿Que puedo tener mal para que la imagen la haga vacia?

si le hago un echo a `$ImagenRedimensionada` y a `$ImagenGrande` me devuelve Resource id #5 Resource id #4

¿es normal que no coincidan los id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya lo tengo resuelto.
por si le sirve a alguien esta ha sido la solución:

```
function Subir_Imagen($Input, $Ruta, $Foto, $Miniatura, $AnchoMax, $AltoMax){
    $Respuesta = array();
    $NombreOriginal  = basename($_FILES[$Input]['name']);
    $Extension = pathinfo($NombreOriginal, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if ($Foto != '') { //Si el nombre esta vacio uso el orginal
        $Nombre = $Foto.'.'.$Extension;
    } else {
        $Nombre = $_FILES[$Input]['name'];
    }

//Ruta de los archivos
    $ImagenOriginal = $Ruta.basename($Nombre);
    $ImagenMini = $Ruta."Mini_".basename($Nombre);

//Subo la imagen
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$Input]['tmp_name'],$ImagenOriginal)) {
        //redimensiono la imagen si es demasiado grande.
        if ($Extension == "jpg" || $Extension == "jpeg") { $ImagenGrande = imagecreatefromjpeg($ImagenOriginal);
            } elseif ($Extension == "png") { $ImagenGrande = imagecreatefrompng($ImagenOriginal);
            } elseif ($Extension == "gif") { $ImagenGrande = imagecreatefromgif($ImagenOriginal);
            }

        $x = imagesx($ImagenGrande);
        $y = imagesy($ImagenGrande);

        if($x <= $AnchoMax && $y <= $AltoMax){
            $Respuesta['Script'] .= "Alerta('La imagen ya estaba optimizada.','success',3000);";
            return json_encode($Respuesta);
        }

        if ($x >= $y) {
            $nuevax = $AnchoMax;
            $nuevay = $nuevax * $y / $x;
            $Mininuevax = 400;
            $Mininuevay = $Mininuevax * $y / $x;
        } else {
            $nuevay = $AltoMax;
            $nuevax = $x / $y * $nuevay;
            $Mininuevay = 400;
            $Mininuevax = $x / $y * $Mininuevay;
        }

        $ImagenNueva = imagecreatetruecolor($nuevax, $nuevay);
        imagecopyresized($ImagenNueva, $ImagenGrande, 0, 0, 0, 0, floor($nuevax), floor($nuevay), $x, $y);

        if ($Extension == "jpg" || $Extension == "jpeg") { imagejpeg($ImagenNueva,$ImagenOriginal,100);
            } elseif ($Extension == "png") { imagepng($ImagenNueva,$ImagenOriginal,100);
            } elseif ($Extension == "gif") { imagegif($ImagenNueva,$ImagenOriginal,100); }

    if($Miniatura == "SI") { //creo la miniatura
            $Miniatura = imagecreatetruecolor($Mininuevax, $Mininuevay);
            imagecopyresized($Miniatura, $ImagenGrande, 0, 0, 0, 0, floor($Mininuevax), floor($Mininuevay), $x, $y);

        if ($Extension == "jpg" || $Extension == "jpeg") { imagejpeg($Miniatura,$ImagenMini,100);
            } elseif ($Extension == "png") { imagepng($Miniatura,$ImagenMini,100);
            } elseif ($Extension == "gif") { imagegif($Miniatura,$ImagenMini,100); }
            imagedestroy($Miniatura);
    }

    } else {
        $Respuesta['Script'] .= "Alerta(Ocurrió un error al subir la imagen.','error',3000);";
    }
//imagedestroy($ImagenRedimensionada);
        $Respuesta['Script'] .= "Alerta('La imagen se ha optimizado correctamente.','success',3000);";
    return json_encode($Respuesta);
}
```

y para llamarlo y recibir las respuestas en json es asi:

```
$FondoPantalla= Subir_Imagen('input_name','/images/fondos/','Nombrefoto','SI',300,260);
$Fondodepantalla = json_decode($FondoPantalla);
$Respuesta['Script'] .= $Fondodepantalla->Script;
```

La parte de json es solo para recibir avisos de que ha hecho, se pueden quitar sin problemas que la función funcionaria igualmente.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo que tengo es la siguiente función para la redimensión

```
function redimensionarJPEG ($origen, $destino, $ancho_max, $alto_max, $fijar) 
{

    $info_imagen= getimagesize($origen);
    $ancho=$info_imagen[0];
    $alto=$info_imagen[1];
    if ($ancho>=$alto)
    {
        $nuevo_alto= round($alto * $ancho_max / $ancho,0);
        $nuevo_ancho=$ancho_max;
    }
    else
    {
        $nuevo_ancho= round($ancho * $alto_max / $alto,0);
        $nuevo_alto=$alto_max;
    }
    switch ($fijar)
    {
        case "ancho":
            $nuevo_alto= round($alto * $ancho_max / $ancho,0);
            $nuevo_ancho=$ancho_max;
            break;
        case "alto":
            $nuevo_ancho= round($ancho * $alto_max / $alto,0);
            $nuevo_alto=$alto_max;
            break;
        default:
            $nuevo_ancho=$nuevo_ancho;
            $nuevo_alto=$nuevo_alto;
            break;
    }
    $imagen_nueva= imagecreatetruecolor($nuevo_ancho,$nuevo_alto);
    $imagen_vieja= imagecreatefromjpeg($origen);
    imagecopyresampled($imagen_nueva, $imagen_vieja, 0, 0, 0, 0,$nuevo_ancho, $nuevo_alto, $ancho, $alto);
    imagejpeg($imagen_nueva,$destino);
    imagedestroy($imagen_nueva);
    imagedestroy($imagen_vieja);
}
```

donde los parametros son:

$origen: Imagen que se ha subido 
$destino: Imagen que quiero crear 
$ancho_max: Anchura máxima de la foto, para su redimensión 
$alto_max: Altura máxima de la foto, para su redimensión 
$fijar: lado que queremos fijar para la redimensión.

Para `GIF` y `PNG` es lo mismo

Comment: Ya había visto tu codigo en otra respuesta :) pero es solo para jpg y tampoco veo nada distinto respecto a la mia. excepto que tu el imagecreatefrom* lo pones despues de el imagecreatetruecolor.

Comment: para `GIF` sería lo mismo, pero poniendo `imagecreatefromgif($origen)`

Comment: Ya lo he resuelto, he puesto una respuesta con el codigo por si te sirve para el tuyo y que acepte todo tipo de imágenes :). Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda de todas formas, te doy un positivo aunque no haya usado el código :)